# Hive query group by calculating average on specific field

Tags: hadoop, hive

Folks we have following data and we are not able to write HIVE query for the same.

```
   CUSTOMER_NAME PRODUCT_NAME PRICE OCCURANCE ID
   customer1,    product1,    20,       1
   customer1,    product2,    30,       2
   customer1,    product1,    25,       3
   customer1,    product1,    20,       1
   customer1,    product2,    20,       2
   customer1,    product2,    30,       2
```

Now we are expecting below output.

basically we want average price for customer and product.

```
     First we need to average price at customer1,product1,occuranceID level.        

e.g. customer1,product1,20 (AVG is 20 for occurance 1), 1
     customer1,product1,25 (AVG is 25 for occurance 3) , 3

      Now once again we have to average based on count of occurance (we will remove occurance ID here)

      output will be given blow.

      customer1,product1,20+25/2


      How to write HIVE query for this ?
```

Comment: I donot know how to write this in first place and not able to write anything

Comment: Little confusing your required output. Can u tell in words, what exactly you want to achieve , i mean averageof(price ? - first and last occurrences )  ???

Comment: I have modified problem statement basically we need to take AVERAGE or AVERAGE.

Comment: Question addressed @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864735/group-by-one-combination-and-once-again-group-it-for-other-items/23869361#23869361